# Is there any flaw in applying Maximum Modulus and Minimum modulus theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis

What additional information can be concluded about the function?

(a)A function analytic in the closed disk:$|z|\leq 4$ with $\inf|f(z)|=5$ on the circle $|z|=4$ and with $f(1)=i$

(b)A function analytic in the closed disk:$|z|\leq 1$ with $\sup|f(z)|=2$ on the circle $|z|=1$ and with $f(0)=-2i$

My Attempt.

(a) $f(z)=i, \forall z:|z|\leq 4$, By Minimum modulus principle.

(b) $f(z)=-2i, \forall z:|z|\leq 1$, By maximum modulus principle.
Am I correct?
Is there any flaw in applying Maximum Modulus and Minimum modulus theorem?

Comment: (b) is correct, (a) is incorrect. To fix (a), think about the following. What are the hypotheses for the Minimum Modulus Principle and what is the conclusion? If the conclusion doesn't hold, what must be true about the hypotheses?

Comment: Suppose f(z) is analytic in
a domain D, and that $f(z) \neq 0$ in D. Then |f(z)| cannot attain a minimum
in D unless f(z) is constant. If f(z) is also continuous on D, $\overline D$ compact,
then |f(z)| attains a minimum on the boundary.

Comment: Here $f(z)\neq 0$ can't say.

Comment: @zugzug But what additional information can be drawn?

Comment: If $f(z)=i$, so $|f(z)|=1$ for all $|z|\leq 4$, how can the infinimum of the modulus be $5$?

Comment: You need the function to be analytic and not have any zeros inside $D$. Clearly, the conclusion of the Minimum modulus principle is not holding since there's an element inside the disk with modulus equal to $1$, which is less than the infinimum of the modulus on the boundary.

Comment: Yes. That is not possible. right?

Comment: It is IF $f$ is analytic and has no zeros inside. You are only told that $f$ is analytic. What must be true?

Comment: So, such function doesn't exists. right?@zugzug

Comment: So, conclusion, must be no such function exists, with this property.right?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to put our conversation into an answer that I hope will help for (a).

If you have a statement of the form $P$ implies $Q$.  This is logically equivalent to not $Q$ implies not $P$.

**Minimum modulus principle:**: If $f$ is analytic on and inside $D$ and $f(z)\neq 0$ for all $z$, then $f$ attains its minimum modulus on the boundary.

P: $f$ is analytic on and inside $D$ and $f(z)\neq 0$ for all $z$.

Q: $f$ attains its minimum modulus on the boundary.

In your problem, $f$ does **not** attain its minimum modulus on the boundary. We know this since $\inf |f(z)|=5$ on the boundary, but for a point inside, $|f(1)|=|i|=1$.

Hence, you have not Q, which implies not P.

Not P: $f$ is not analytic on and inside $D$ or $f(z)=0$ for some $z$. What can you conclude?

Comment: Henc, $f(z)=0$ for all $z$. right?

Comment: but it contradict the fact that $f(1)=i$.

Comment: The negation of $f(z)\neq 0$ for all $z$ is $f(z)=0$ for some $z$.

Comment: okay. you mean conclusion is only, f has a zero in D. Right?

Comment: yes, at least one.

Comment: what else can we conclude?can you give hints?

Comment: can you give an example of such a function?